# how do I point latest Dart version to this project?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, google-codelab

I am trying to run the code on below project but has been noticing the error about Dart SK version (See below error).

Tried: pub get on YML file, get dependencies on main.dart file but same error. Any help? I read earlier resolution which says adding the version at YML file but it did not work. I also, installed the 2.17.6 in my machine and configured the Environment variable but no luck. Help please

Project from Github:
git clone https://github.com/flutter/codelabs.git
cd codelabs/boring_to_beautiful/step_01/

Error on Android Studio:
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Running "flutter pub get" in step_01...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.1.

Because myartist requires SDK version >=2.17.6 <3.3.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because myartist requires SDK version >=2.17.6 <3.3.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

The pubspec.yml has below
environment:
sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.3.0"

Comment: Update the question with output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: You have Dart 2.17.1.  The packages you depend on require 2.17.6.  Either upgrade your Dart/Flutter SDKs or depend on older versions of those packages that have lower SDK requirements.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.